# python classes getters and setters static method and class method

Tags: python, class

```
class Spam(object): 
#a_string = 'candy'
def __init__(self, sold=0, cost=0): 
    self.sold = sold
    self.cost = cost
@staticmethod
def total_cost():
    return True

@classmethod
def items_sold(cls, how_many):

@property
def silly_walk(self):
    return print (self.a_string)

@silly_walk.setter
def silly_walk(self, new_string):
    self.a_string = new_string.upper()

def do_cost(self):
    if self.total_cost():
        print('Total cost is:', self.cost)
```

.

```
  from spam import Spam

def main ():
    cost = 25
    sold = 100
    a_string = 'sweets'
    sp = Spam(100, 25)
    sp.do_cost()
    sw = Spam.silly_walk(a_string)
    sw.silly_walk()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so im new to python and i don't understand how to use the setters and getters in this. so what i want to do is:

use @property to create a setter and getter for a property named silly_walk. Have the setter upper case the silly_walk string.
Show example code that would access the static method.
Show example code that would use the silly_walk setter and getter.

im getting very confused with what "self" does in the class and im not sure if what im doing is correct

update: 
problem was the @classmethod not having a return and indentation error, so everything is fixed thanks everybody

Comment: i was looking for hours if that helps and i have a hard time understanding the stuff. and i wasn't trying to throw random code together, so please don't be a jerk about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is convention. Since you're inside a class, you don't have functions there you have methods. Methods expect a reference to the object calling them as the first argument, which by convention is named `self`. You can call it anything you like.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(itsa_me_maaaario, name):
        itsa_me_maaario.name = "Mario"
```

That works just as well.

As for the rest of your code -- what's your QUESTION there? Looks like your setter is a bit weird, but other than that it should work mostly okay. This is better:

```
class Spam(object): # inherit from object in py2 for new-style classes
    def __init__(self, a_string, sold=0, cost=0) # put the positional arg first
        ...
    @staticmethod
    def total_cost():
        # you have to do something meaningful here. A static method can't access
        # any of the objects attributes, it's really only included for grouping
        # related functions to their classes.
    @classmethod
    def items_sold(cls, how_many):
        # the first argument to a classmethod is the class, not the object, so
        # by convention name it cls. Again this should be something relevant to
        # the class not to the object.
    @property
    def silly_walk(self):
        return self.a_string
        # don't call itself.
    @silly_walk.setter
    def silly_walk(self, new_string):
        self.a_string = new_string
        # it really just hides the attribute.
```

For instance I have a class I built to abstract a computer system I'm in charge of. It might be something like:

```
class System(object):
    type_ = "Base system"
    def __init__(self, sitenum, devicenum, IP):
        self._sitenum = sitenum
        self._devicenum = devicenum
        self._IP = IP
        # the leading underscores are a flag to future coders that these are
        # "private" variables. Nothing stopping someone from using it anyway,
        # because System()._IP is still that attribute, but it makes it clear
        # that they're not supposed to be used that way.
    @staticmethod
    def ping_system(IP):
        subprocess.call(["ping",IP], shell=True) # OH GOD SECURITY FLAW HERE
        # group this with Systems because maybe that's how I want it? It's an
        # aesthetic choice. Note that this pings ANY system and requires an
        # argument of an IP address!
    @classmethod
    def type_of_system(cls):
        return cls.type_
        # imagine I had a bunch of objects that inherited from System, each w/
        # a different type_, but they all inherit this....
    @property
    def description(self):
        return "Site {}, Device {} @ {}".format(self._sitenum,
                                                self._devicenum,
                                                self._IP)
    @description.setter
    def description(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 3:
            self._sitenum, self._devicenum, self._IP = args
        elif len(args) == 1 and len(args[0]) == 3:
            self._sitenum, self._devicenum, self._IP = args[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Redefine description as Sitenum, Devicenum, IP")
```

Example:

```
computer = System(1, 1, '192.168.100.101')
System.ping_system('192.160.100.101') # works
computer.type_of_system # "Base system"
computer.description # "Site 1, Device 1 @ 192.168.100.101"
new_description = [1, 2, '192.168.100.102']
computer.description = new_description
# invokes description.setter
computer._devicenum # is 2 after the setter does its magic.
```

Comment: kool thanks and yea my question is about the setters and getters i don't understand them. my professor wants us to use tha @ properties thing, don't know how to use that also. any idea  whats wrong with what i got

Comment: @user3804711 and my second more substantial edit with a real possible example class. Also, not to toot my own horn, I wrote that `class System` without testing and it works perfectly! :D

Comment: i keep getting this IndentationError: expected an indented block at the @property

Comment: hmm that was strange i just added a extra space and it worked but now @silly_walk.setter
NameError: name 'silly_walk' is not defined

Comment: @user3804711 that class is a dummy. It's missing vital bits of stuff to hold it together. Chances are you just need to put some `pass` statements in or write some meaningful code in the methods and it will work fine as written. Regardless, my `System` class is a much better example.